# Preserve form state over page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to come up with a way to preserve form state over page refresh/reload. So far I have found [dumbformstate](https://github.com/sebringj/jquery.dumbformstate) plug-in. Which works beautifully. The only problem I have is with dynamically injected fields. They do not persist over the refresh. Anyone have any suggestions that would work with dynamically injected fields?

Or if anyone has used this particular plug-in know if it is supposed to work with dynamic, fields, and I am just inserting then the wrong way? This is how I do it:

```
success: function(data) {
    var html = $("<div><h3>"+catName+"</h3></div>");
    html.find("h3").data("category",catName);
    subCatContainer.append(html);
    subCatsFetched = subCatContainer.find("h3");

    $(data).each(function(){
        var input = $('<label>'+this.sub_cat_name+'<input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat[]" value="'+this.sub_cat_id+'" /></label>');
        html.append(input);
    });
}
```

Or is it possible that fields do not persist due to them being inside a `div` element? There is reason why they have to be inside of div, so there is nothing I can really do about it realistically.

Or another thing I was trying to look for, is some generic "DOM preserver", where I can just take some arbitrary piece of DOM, and preserve it via refreshes (cookies/localstorage). but in that case I am guessing the values of inputs will end up not being preserved?

EDIT:

This question does not really have an answer. As my assumption of what this plug-in does, was wrong. All it does is stores information about the state off all elements of the form, it does not do anything to preserve the dynamically generated DOM elements. After using some localStorage to store the generated DOM, sates of all inputs would persist as expected!

Answer (score 1):

How about if you instantiate the plugin after automatically filling the fields? Something like this in your Javascript:

```
//Load field's content
loadData( ... );

//Instantiate plugin
$('your-form').dumbFormState( ... )
```

Does that work?

Comment: I tried to do something along the lines of instantiating it after every change to the form. But still did not pick up the dynamic fields.

Comment: If you look into the plugin you will see: [line 150] $this.bind('blur.dumbFormState focus.dumbFormState click.dumbFormState keyup.dumbFormState change.dumbFormState', function () { ... } So you should be able to do what I said. Also it is not necesary to call instantiation after every change, do it only once. Please post your code to see what is happening.

Comment: OK, I am after examining the JSON that this plug in stores. And the information about the dynamic fields, does indeed get preserved over the page loads, and the plug in works as expected. The problem is, that the HTML does not get preserved, and from what I can see this plug-in is not supposed to do it. So i will ne to somehow make it myself, i suppose, i will have to use some local storage to store the HTML from generated DOM, and if I achieve that this plug in will handle the filling in of the form elements.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood your question. Yes, if you want to store the HTML you will have to use some sort of browser storage; note that it only works on the user's browser and wont work if the user open another browser. If you are going to store HTML, you probably want to see what templates are. This is a good place to start: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: No you did not misunderstood. I myself had misunderstood what this plugin actually does. Anyway, I am now working on persisting the form HTML, and I still have some issues. But when I do persist the HTML, indeed the state of the generated fields does get preserved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad you resolved your problem.